# Incremental loading not loading all data

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

I have implemented incremental loading like this:

```
public class IncrementalDataSource : ObservableCollection<Files>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{
    private int id;
    private int itemsPerPage;
    private int currentPage;

    public IncrementalMediaEntrySource(int ID, int ipp = 4)
    {
        HasMoreItems = true;
        id = ID;
        itemsPerPage = ipp;
        currentPage = 1;
    }

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        var dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(
            async () =>
            {
                uint resultCount = 0;
                var result = await GetData(id, itemsPerPage, currentPage++);

                if (result == null || result.Count() == 0)
                {
                    HasMoreItems = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    resultCount = (uint)result.Count();

                    await dispatcher.RunAsync(
                        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () =>
                        {
                            foreach (var item in result)
                                this.Add(item);
                        });
                }

                return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = resultCount };

            }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }
}
```

But it's not loading all data. It only gets around 16 items from 100+ items. If I change *itemsPerPage* from 4 to 10, it gets all items. But it takes a bit too long to load by 10 items, so I would like to stay with 4 items. And of course I would like to know, what is causing this, to avoid that. Where could be the problem?

**UPDATE:**
A friend of mine suggested to add "fake" objects, if *itemsPerPage* is less than 7(minimums number with which it is working correctly), so that total objects recieved would be 7. I tried that, and it actually worked, but of course added empty objects, which is totally useless. So I added check before adding objects to `ObservableCollection<Files>` like this:

```
foreach (var item in result)
    if (item.Id != null) this.Add(item);
```

But then it is not working again. So maybe the problem is in adding? But I cannot think of possible cause for this...

Comment: Well, that `currentPage++` isn't thread-safe, so if you're reading concurrently (or if you're unlucky with caching), that might be a problem. Try incrementing before the `Task.Run`. The higher amount of items might work exactly because it's slower if this is the problem. I don't see anything else - there might be a problem in the `GetData` method.

Comment: @Luaan Incrementing before `Task.Run` changes nothing. `GetData` alone works perfectly, so I doubt that problem is there.

Comment: Well, you'll have to debug, then. I don't think there's anything in the code you've posted we can use to help you (though I'm not an expert on observables, so I might be missing something silly and obvious). Log how many times `GetData` is called, with which parameters, and what results it returns. Check that you're not getting exceptions. See what happens if you add an artifical sleep after `GetData` to mimic how long the 10 items take to load.

Comment: @Luaan I've done debugging, and I can't find anything. If `itemsPerPage` is somewhere between 1 and 6, it's not getting all data, but if it is 7 or more it is getting all data. No idea why. No exceptions thrown and adding `Task.Delay` is not helping as well.